# Extract words from a string in spark hadoop with scala

Tags: sql, regex, scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I was using the code below to extract strings I needed in Spark SQL. But now I am working with more data in Spark Hadoop and I want to extract strings. I tried the same code, but it does not work.

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myapp").setMaster("local[*]")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}
import java.util.regex.Pattern

//User Defined function to extract
def toExtract(str: String) = {      
  val pattern = Pattern.compile("@\\w+")
  val tmplst = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[String]
  val matcher = pattern.matcher(str)
  while (matcher.find()) {
    tmplst += matcher.group()
  }
  tmplst.mkString(",")
}

val Extract = udf(toExtract _)
val values = List("@always_nidhi @YouTube no i dnt understand bt i loved the music nd their dance awesome all the song of this mve is rocking")
val df = sc.parallelize(values).toDF("words")
df.select(Extract(col("words"))).show()
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're using Spark not the way its meant to. Your DataFrame isn't partitioned at all. Use:
`val values = List("@always_nidhi", "@YouTube", "no", "i", "dnt", "understand" ...)`. That way, each bulk of words will be assigned to a different partition, different JVMs and/or clusters (depending on the total number of partitions and size of data). In your solution, the entire sentence is assigned to a specific partition and thus there's no parallelism nor distribution.

Second, you don't have to use a UDF (try to avoid those in general).
In order to find your regex, you can simply execute:
`dataFrame.filter(col("words") rlike "@\\w+")`

Hope it helps :-)